# Post SOAP Envelope to WCF service

Tags: wcf, soap

I have the following SOAP message that i want to post it to my WCF Service and get response.

```
"<s:Envelope xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\" xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\r\n  <s:Header>\r\n    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">http://schemas.devleap.com/OrderService/IOrderService/InsertOrder</a:Action>\r\n    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:4cb619b7-365b-4108-880f-b302029d03c2</a:MessageID>\r\n    <a:ReplyTo>\r\n      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>\r\n    </a:ReplyTo>\r\n  </s:Header>\r\n  <s:Body>\r\n    <InsertOrder xmlns=\"http://schemas.devleap.com/OrderService\">\r\n      <order xmlns:d4p1=\"http://schemas.devleap.com/OrderService/Order\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\r\n        <d4p1:IdCustomer>2</d4p1:IdCustomer>\r\n        <d4p1:IdOrder>46</d4p1:IdOrder>\r\n        <d4p1:OrderItems xmlns:d5p1=\"http://schemas.devleap.com/OrderService/OrderItems\" xmlns:d5p2=\"http://schemas.devleap.com/OrderService/OrderItem\">\r\n          <d5p1:OrderItem>\r\n            <d5p2:IdProduct>P01</d5p2:IdProduct>\r\n            <d5p2:Quantity>5</d5p2:Quantity>\r\n            <d5p2:EuroPrice>20</d5p2:EuroPrice>\r\n          </d5p1:OrderItem>\r\n          <d5p1:OrderItem>\r\n            <d5p2:IdProduct>P01</d5p2:IdProduct>\r\n            <d5p2:Quantity>5</d5p2:Quantity>\r\n            <d5p2:EuroPrice>20</d5p2:EuroPrice>\r\n          </d5p1:OrderItem>\r\n        </d4p1:OrderItems>\r\n      </order>\r\n    </InsertOrder>\r\n  </s:Body>\r\n</s:Envelope>"
```

How can i post this SOAP to the WCF service?
I tried this but i get "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error." exception.

```
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {

            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");


            var response = client.UploadString("http://localhost:8000/OrderService", data);

        }
```

If i remove the header from Envelope and add:

```
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://schemas.devleap.com/OrderService/IOrderService/InsertOrder\"");
```

i get the same error.

If i put

```
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

i get exception that server expects "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8".

If someone knows how to call it right please help.

Thank you,
Adrya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more digging i managed to post the SOAP to the service.
Here is code:

```
        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadData("http://localhost:8000/OrderService", "POST", byteArray);
        Console.WriteLine("\nResponse received was {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: -1: you have solved the wrong problem. You should have followed the suggestion from marc_s. You could have switched between services simply by choosing the URL of the service.

Comment: I solved my problem. I can't do it "normal way" because everything happens at runtime. At runtime i don't know the services, i don't have their proxy classes, all i have is the URL and SOAP request.